# Link to a static .lib compiled with VS2010 when I'm compiling with VS2013?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I have third party library that is a static .lib file that they tell me was compiled with VS2010. We develop our application in VS2013 and need to link to this library.

When we try, we get this error:

> error C1047: The object or library file '.../xxx.lib' was created with
>   an older compiler than other objects; rebuild old objects and
>   libraries

Does this mean we will have to use VS2010 compiler to link to it? (we cannot get a recompiled version of the library)

Comment: Note that with the switch to the [Universal CRT](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/) for VS 2015, that old static library may not even link at all with VS 2015. You should make plans to replace that black-box library at some point if you can't get it rebuilt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More or less; yes.

Generally, all parts of a C++ program needs to be compiled and linked with the *exact* same compiler (including exact compiler version).

Usually you also need to use the same compiler options when building the different parts.

There are exceptions, but that's the general rule of thumb.

There is no standardized C++ ABI.

Comment: Not only the same compiler, but the same options too, to a certain extent (notably, the runtime library and `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL` should match).

Comment: For example, you usually will only get pain if you link debug and non-debug objects/libs in the same executable.

Comment: @JesperJuhl what do you mean "no standardized C++ ABI" do you mean API?

Comment: No. I mean A**B**I - as in "Application **Binary** Interface". C++ does not have a standardized one. Meaning that you cannot rely on objects that have been compiled by different compilers (or even different minor versions of the same) to be binary compatible (linkable, callable). Meaning that for proper results you *have* to use the same compiler/linker/options for *all* components of the final result (binary or library) - you cannot mix and match.

Comment: One option here is to use the VS 2010 toolset to create a DLL that wraps up your use of that static library in a C-callable functions, then your main application can use the DLL instead of the static library as DLLs do have a well-defined ABI.

Comment: Sure. Wrap everything in `extern "C"` functions and put that in a library (using VS 2010) and then use *that* library. That would work (I think), but that's a hack ;) But a nice one that might solve OP's problem.. assuming that is doable..

Comment: Even a C wrapper is not foolproof -- that solves the ABI mismatch between the application and the library, but not the mismatch between the CRTs that the two are referencing. The library would have to link against a static version of the CRT, which I don't believe MS supports (e.g. between VS2013 and VS2015 the CRT was changed heavily internally, and libraries linked dynamically against the older one no longer link in to applications built against the new one without being recompiled).

Comment: I didn't think about that - nice catch. So we are back to "build everything with the *exact* same compiler and options and link with the same linker" - where we started.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Would I experience this same issue if they had built a DLL instead of a static library, still using the older compiler?

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't use Windows much and don't know, off the top of my head, what ABI guarantees DLL's provide.

Comment: @JesperJuhl do you know if Microsoft provides any documentation explaining the non-compatibility between the compiler versions? My searches haven't lead me to anything

Comment: They document breaking changes for the different VS versions here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344(v=vs.140).aspx you can also read the release notes for the different versions for more info as well as https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/ where that stuff comes up once in a while when they talk about new releases of VS. That's all I have.